# Video Game AI State Change

Tags: c#, ai, unity3d

I have here a snippet of code from a simple video game AI enemy.  The basic idea behind the enemy is that he can be in one of a few states.  By default he is in a patrolling state, where he moves around at a slow speed to random points within a circle.  While in this state, he is rolling every X seconds to switch to one of his more interesting states.  Currently, he may either transition into a state where he spins rapidly while patrolling as stated above, but at a much faster move speed. Or he will can instead go into a stationary defensive spin.  Here is the current method which handles this state change:

```
IEnumerator RollForStateChange()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(RollTickTime); 

        if (CanRollForStateChange)
        {
            float spinAttackRoll = Random.Range(0, 100);

            if (spinAttackRoll <= SpinAttackChancePerTick)
            {
                StartCoroutine(SpinAttackTimer());
                continue;
            }

            float spinDefenseRoll = Random.Range(0, 100);

            if(spinDefenseRoll <= SpinDefenceChancePerTick)
            {
                StartCoroutine(DefenseSpinTimer());
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this sort of dice rolling method works just fine for now, I can't help but feel that it is more likely to choose the spin attack, since that roll goes first.  I can also see this becoming more inefficient if I wanted to add more states for the enemy to transition into.  However, I am struggling to come up with a more elegant way to decide which state the enemy should go into.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that this roll is biased.  Instead of using a fixed range and less-than for your rolls, you should just roll once and use specific ranges to choose which action is taken.  Something like:

```
int spinAttackChancePerTickMin = 0;
int spinAttackChancePerTickMax = 50;

int spinDefenceChancePerTickMin = 50;
int spinDefenceChancePerTickMax = 100;

int roll = Random.Range(0, 100);

if (roll >= spinAttackChancePerTickMin && 
    roll < spinAttackChancePerTickMax)
{
    StartCoroutine(SpinAttackTimer());
    continue;
}

StartCoroutine(DefenseSpinTimer());
```

Comment: Please do not use `else` and `else if` any time you interrupt flow control using `break`, `continue`, `return`.  By doing so, we can reduce the amount of code that needs to be tracked in the flow path and potentially reduce the amount indentations.

Comment: @Snowhawk04 So just make that an `if`?

Comment: In the situation where you are breaking the flow, just make them `if`s.  In this situation, since we would only be transitioning into 2 possible states, you could remove the 2nd conditional and just run the defense coroutine (drop the final continue as well since the loop would be finishing anyway).